# Determining Projection using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am very new to QGIS and I am trying to determine the spatial projection and the units of distance of a certain raster file.  The closest thing I can find is the CRS, which is set to some sort of custom value of USER:100000.  However, I'm not sure if that's what I'm supposed to be looking for.

Also, if that is what I'm looking for, how do I determine the units of distance from the file?

Comment: Is the raster *in* a projection, or put another way is it actually georeferenced? You don't give any details of the raster - format, if it's a single file or has accompanying files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the projection information is `Rightclick -> Set CRS for Layer`.

This will report the `USER:100000` you already know, and the parameters for the projection as well.

`+units=...` will give you the units of the projection.

Comment: Okay, so USER:100000 is the projection?  I thought there would be something that identified it as a UTM projection or other type of projection.

Comment: It is the custom projection that QGIS has created because it could not identify it as one of the official EPSG definitions. If you look under `Settings -> Custom CRS`, you will see the full definition, something like `+proj=lcc +lat_1=50 +lat_2=50 +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-107 +x_0=5632642.22547 +y_0=4612545.65137 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`.